# How to optimize memory and speed for repeated survey-simulations in R?

Tags: r, performance, loops, memory, multidimensional-array

I am attempting to conduct a simulation in which I have 257 sub-distrct and a list of villages within each sub-district, each with a known percentage of people that have a certain condition. I want to iterate over five numbers of villages (`n_village` in {5, 10, 20 ,30 ,50}) and five numbers of people per village (`n_person` in {10, 15, 20, 25, 30}) and for each I want to repeat a survey 1000 times.  That means 5 * 5 * 257 * 1000 = 6,425,000 results.  Furthermore, my list of sites is 4,999, 3836 for one country, and 1163 for another.

For all sub-district:

1. Randomly select `n_village` villages.
2. Within each resulting village, randomly select `n_person` individuals and count how many people have the condition.
3. Calculate the estimated district-level percentage of people with the conndition, along with the confidence interval for said percentage.

My first attempt involved iterating over everything with mapply and saving the results randomly sampled villages to a list, but that was taking very, very long.

I made a lot of headway using nested `tibbles` and `pmap`, but I am now running into memory issues and performance slow-downs.

Below is a 10 sub-district approximation of my approach.  I am also restricting the example to 10 simulations.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tictoc)

admin_unit_df <- 
  tibble(
    shapeName_0 = "Country 1", 
    shapeName_1 = "Region 1",
    shapeName_2 = "District 1",
    shapeName_3 = paste0("Sub-district ", 1:10)
  )

sampling_frame_df <- 
  tibble(
    site_id = 1:500,
    shapeName_3 = sample(admin_unit_df$shapeName_3, 500, replace = T),
    site.prev = runif(500)
  ) %>%
  group_by(
    shapeName_3
  ) %>%
  nest()

sim_parms_df <-
  expand.grid(
    "n_village" = c(2, 5, 10, 15, 20),
    "n_person"  = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50),
    "sim_id"    = 1:10
  ) %>%
  arrange(n_village, n_person, sim_id) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  rowwise() 

simulations_df <-
  admin_unit_df %>%
  mutate(
    data = sampling_frame_df$data,
    
    sim_parms = list(sim_parms_df)
  )

simulations_df

simulations_df$sim_parms[[1]]
```

I then randomly sample the villages from the data

```
tic()
simulations_df %<>%
  mutate(
    sim_parms = 
      pmap(
        .l = 
          list(
            "sim_parms" = sim_parms,
            "data" = data
          ),
        .f = 
          function(sim_parms, data){
            n_site_avail = nrow(data)
            
            sim_parms %>%
              mutate(
                samples =
                  list(
                    data[sample(x = 1:n_site_avail, size = min(n_village, n_site_avail), replace = F), ] %>%
                      as_tibble() %>%
                      rowwise()
                  )
              )
          }
    )
  )
toc()
```

After this, I use pmap to iterate and randomly sample the number of people positive for the condition at each village.

```
tic()
simulations_df %<>%
  mutate(
    sim_parms = 
      pmap(
        .l = 
          list(
            "sim_parms" = sim_parms
          ),
        .f = 
          function(sim_parms){
            # cat(names(sim_parms), "\n")
            
            sim_parms %>%
              ungroup() %>%
              mutate(
                samples = 
                  pmap(
                    .l = list("samples" = samples, "n_person" = n_person),
                    .f = function(samples, n_person){
                      # cat(names(samples), "\n")
                      samples %>%
                        mutate(
                          n_pos = rbinom(n = 1, size = n_person, p = site.prev),
                          p_hat = n_pos / n_person
                        )
                    }
                  )
              )
            
          }
    )
  )
toc()
```

Things start to slow down and blow up here, but I've successfully completed this.

The next thing I want to do is use `binom.test()` to calculate the lower and upper confidence interval bounds for the estimated prevalence.

This is a very basic analysis, yet it takes quite a long time.  At some point, I aim to use lme4 to conduct a multilevel model analysis for all 1000 simulations.

Any tips on how to make this task tractable?  Is there a way to loop and save results *without* saving all of the intermediary values?

As an aside -- saving to RDS and reading the RDS takes very, very long. Any suggestions to speed this up?

Comment: When a survey is administered in a village, are the individuals to be surveyed sampled with or without replacement? `rbinom` would correspond to a sample with replacement (meaning the same individual could be surveyed more than once for each simulation repetition).

Comment: in the sample random village step, you have a seemingly purposeless  %>%
                      rowwise() that slows down your process a good deal.

Comment: @jblood94 - with or without replacement is not particularly relevant.  My question is about optimizing memory and computational speed.  Any answer should be able to improve code performance in either setting.

Comment: In order to "Calculate the estimated district-level percentage of people with the condition", you would need to also know the number of people in each village, no?

Comment: @Nir Graham - I make the "samples" data frame rowwise so that I can sample the correct number of people using the appropriate, row-specific success probability.  Now, does `rowwise` hurt performance because I am calling a function repeatedly?  Or are `rowwise` data frames more memory intensive somehow? Please clarify *how* rowwise  is slowing me down.  And thanks for weighing in!

Comment: @jblood94 - Again, the specifics of my survey are irrelevant to my question.  I have considered all of the possible dimensions of my actual survey simulations... I have simply included a simplified version here for clarity, *to keep focus on the relevant issues*, in this case, code performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can gain a lot of performance by operating on a big `data.frame` instead of long `list`s/nested columns with small `data.frame` entries. A grouped `data.frame` is usually way faster to operate on.

Also, try to avoid carrying grouped data (`rowwise()` is also a grouping)  around for operations where the grouping is unnecessary. The new `.by/by` argument for `dplyr` verbs is excellent since it allows you to apply the grouping just for the current operation.

Here is a quick rewrite of your code. The idea is to limit the use of `map()` functions and, when used, bind the results into a `data.frame` before applying the next operation.

(I checked the results of my code only briefly, and it seems to produce the same results as yours. Please check closely to make sure that it adheres to your specifications.)

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tictoc)

tic()

set.seed(1)
admin_unit_df <-
  tibble(
    shapeName_0 = "Country 1",
    shapeName_1 = "Region 1",
    shapeName_2 = "District 1",
    shapeName_3 = paste0("Sub-district ", 1:10)
  )

sampling_frame_df <-
  tibble(
    site_id = 1:500,
    shapeName_3 = sample(admin_unit_df$shapeName_3, 500, replace = T),
    site.prev = runif(500),
  )

sim_parms_df <-
  expand.grid(
    "n_village" = c(2, 5, 10, 15, 20),
    "n_person"  = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50),
    "sim_id"    = 1:10
  ) |>
  arrange(n_village, n_person, sim_id) |>
  as_tibble()

samples_df <-
  sim_parms_df |>
  mutate(samples =
           pmap(list(n_village,
                     n_person),
                \(villages, persons) {
                  df = 
                   slice_sample(sampling_frame_df,
                                n = villages,
                                by = shapeName_3)
                })) |>
  unnest(samples) |>
  group_by(shapeName_3, n_village, n_person, sim_id) |>
  mutate(
    n_sites_sampled = n()
  ) |>
  ungroup()

res <-
  samples_df |>
  group_by(shapeName_3, site_id) |>
  mutate(n_pos = rbinom(n = 1, size = n_person, p = site.prev),
         p_hat = n_pos / n_person)

toc()
#> 0.364 sec elapsed

res
#> # A tibble: 24,500 × 8
#> # Groups:   shapeName_3, site_id [500]
#>    n_village n_person sim_id site_id shapeName_3    site.prev n_pos p_hat
#>        <dbl>    <dbl>  <int>   <int> <chr>              <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#>  1         2       10      1     254 Sub-district 9   0.00573     0   0  
#>  2         2       10      1     155 Sub-district 9   0.971      10   1  
#>  3         2       10      1      70 Sub-district 4   0.0764      0   0  
#>  4         2       10      1     451 Sub-district 4   0.0389      0   0  
#>  5         2       10      1     278 Sub-district 7   0.188       3   0.3
#>  6         2       10      1     157 Sub-district 7   0.0392      0   0  
#>  7         2       10      1     258 Sub-district 1   0.167       4   0.4
#>  8         2       10      1     259 Sub-district 1   0.764       9   0.9
#>  9         2       10      1       5 Sub-district 2   0.820       9   0.9
#> 10         2       10      1     496 Sub-district 2   0.305       4   0.4
#> # ℹ 24,490 more rows
```

For the example in the question, this code is ~92% faster than the original code. When we scale up the number of simulations, the difference gets even bigger: At 100 sub-districts, the original code takes 393.428 seconds (on my machine). The refactored code takes 1.288 seconds. That's a speed-up of 99.6%.

Comment: Fantastic!  I made a very small edit.  If you approve the edit, I'll mark yours as the solution.

Comment: I approved the edit. The changes do not have a measurable impact on the performance.

Comment: Great answer.  I love the use of the new base `|>` pipes and `\\` shorthand for function definitions, per the R 4.1 release.  I just ran this for 1000 simulations and 257 subdistricts, resulting in a data frame with 44,860,000 rows. The slice-sample pmap took 20 minutes and the unnesting took 3.5 minutes.

Comment: just out of curiosity, how did you obtain your knowledge/experience of R performance topics? Formal education? Particular online courses or forums?  On-the-job experience? While this change to my code provides immense performance improvements, I'm not sure I fully grasp where the improvements come from. Any recommended resources would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This should be able to run your full dataset to get the 6,425,000 samples in about two minutes.

I moved to `data.table` where I am more comfortable working with large datasets. The biggest time saver here is in vectorizing the call to `rbinom`--we can perform the full sample with a single call by pre-sampling the site prevalences.

First, initialize `admin_unit_df` and the list of sites:

```
library(data.table)

n_subdist <- 10L
n_sites <- 500L
n_sims <- 10L

admin_unit_df <- data.table(
  shapeName_0 = "Country 1", 
  shapeName_1 = "Region 1",
  shapeName_2 = "District 1",
  shapeName_3 = paste0("Sub-district ", 1:n_subdist)
)

dtSites <- setorder(
  data.table(
    site_id = sample(n_sites),
    shapeName_3 = sample(admin_unit_df$shapeName_3, n_sites, 1),
    site.prev = runif(n_sites)
  ), shapeName_3, site_id
)
```

Attach the number of villages in each sub-district to `admin_unit_df`:

```
admin_unit_df[
  dtSites[, .(n_sites = .N), shapeName_3],
  on = "shapeName_3",
  n_sites := n_sites
][]
#>     shapeName_0 shapeName_1 shapeName_2     shapeName_3 n_sites
#>  1:   Country 1    Region 1  District 1  Sub-district 1      47
#>  2:   Country 1    Region 1  District 1  Sub-district 2      52
#>  3:   Country 1    Region 1  District 1  Sub-district 3      55
#>  4:   Country 1    Region 1  District 1  Sub-district 4      48
#>  5:   Country 1    Region 1  District 1  Sub-district 5      66
#>  6:   Country 1    Region 1  District 1  Sub-district 6      46
#>  7:   Country 1    Region 1  District 1  Sub-district 7      53
#>  8:   Country 1    Region 1  District 1  Sub-district 8      36
#>  9:   Country 1    Region 1  District 1  Sub-district 9      41
#> 10:   Country 1    Region 1  District 1 Sub-district 10      56
```

Initialize the table that will hold the final result:

```
dtSamples <- setDT(
  expand.grid(
    shapeName_3 = admin_unit_df$shapeName_3,
    n_village = c(5, 10, 20, 30, 50),
    n_person = seq(10, 30, 5),
    sim_id = 1:n_sims
  )
)
```

For each sample, check if there are enough sites to sample. This should save some time in sampling the site prevalences later.

```
dtSamples[
  admin_unit_df,
  on = "shapeName_3",
  sample_all := n_village >= n_sites
][]
#>           shapeName_3 n_village n_person sim_id sample_all
#>    1:  Sub-district 1         5       10      1      FALSE
#>    2:  Sub-district 2         5       10      1      FALSE
#>    3:  Sub-district 3         5       10      1      FALSE
#>    4:  Sub-district 4         5       10      1      FALSE
#>    5:  Sub-district 5         5       10      1      FALSE
#>   ---                                                     
#> 2496:  Sub-district 6        50       30     10       TRUE
#> 2497:  Sub-district 7        50       30     10      FALSE
#> 2498:  Sub-district 8        50       30     10       TRUE
#> 2499:  Sub-district 9        50       30     10       TRUE
#> 2500: Sub-district 10        50       30     10      FALSE
```

Attach the site prevalences to `dtSamples` for each sub-district.

```
dtSamples[
  dtSites[,.(site.prev = .(site.prev)), shapeName_3],
  on = "shapeName_3",
  site.prev := site.prev
][]
#>           shapeName_3 n_village n_person sim_id sample_all                                                             site.prev
#>    1:  Sub-district 1         5       10      1      FALSE 0.76230401,0.31616402,0.70595874,0.03329785,0.31670605,0.80416111,...
#>    2:  Sub-district 2         5       10      1      FALSE       0.7179183,0.3976863,0.1742246,0.4961729,0.9291852,0.6784859,...
#>    3:  Sub-district 3         5       10      1      FALSE 0.98728870,0.93080725,0.19058676,0.50734847,0.43491126,0.04997108,...
#>    4:  Sub-district 4         5       10      1      FALSE       0.8478491,0.6749693,0.7587742,0.1649277,0.5199866,0.1030520,...
#>    5:  Sub-district 5         5       10      1      FALSE 0.41448144,0.33527002,0.57664015,0.98581762,0.52983240,0.04570276,...
#>   ---                                                                                                                           
#> 2496:  Sub-district 6        50       30     10       TRUE       0.9081889,0.6123581,0.9437069,0.9110006,0.9843121,0.5864228,...
#> 2497:  Sub-district 7        50       30     10       TRUE       0.1990265,0.3181837,0.2668308,0.5253061,0.1336550,0.8646029,...
#> 2498:  Sub-district 8        50       30     10      FALSE 0.16733517,0.07891891,0.13431914,0.54456476,0.70843551,0.58879018,...
#> 2499:  Sub-district 9        50       30     10      FALSE       0.0361343,0.1969452,0.4579978,0.3546803,0.5401674,0.8667377,...
#> 2500: Sub-district 10        50       30     10      FALSE       0.4982402,0.2651319,0.8661620,0.7690203,0.2359905,0.3961777,...
```

Now sample the villages. (I think all we need are the prevalences. If we need to know which villages were sampled, this would need to be modified.)

```
dtSamples[
  , site.prev := lapply(
    1:.N,
    function(i) {
      if(sample_all[i]) {
        site.prev[[i]] 
      } else {
        sample(site.prev[[i]], n_village[i])
      }
    }
  )
][]
#>           shapeName_3 n_village n_person sim_id sample_all                                                             site.prev
#>    1:  Sub-district 1         5       10      1      FALSE                0.05455267,0.91144371,0.10045029,0.82069249,0.07005419
#>    2:  Sub-district 2         5       10      1      FALSE                0.06719633,0.80679034,0.14107399,0.04162033,0.90979810
#>    3:  Sub-district 3         5       10      1      FALSE                0.70489597,0.64529805,0.10316378,0.78458499,0.04997108
#>    4:  Sub-district 4         5       10      1      FALSE                     0.8572546,0.6984983,0.9043646,0.8090858,0.7840790
#>    5:  Sub-district 5         5       10      1      FALSE                0.77213880,0.66895523,0.08206397,0.09116673,0.41448144
#>   ---                                                                                                                           
#> 2496:  Sub-district 6        50       30     10       TRUE       0.9081889,0.6123581,0.9437069,0.9110006,0.9843121,0.5864228,...
#> 2497:  Sub-district 7        50       30     10       TRUE       0.1990265,0.3181837,0.2668308,0.5253061,0.1336550,0.8646029,...
#> 2498:  Sub-district 8        50       30     10      FALSE 0.49136880,0.16733517,0.63565388,0.51755548,0.98739485,0.04692638,...
#> 2499:  Sub-district 9        50       30     10      FALSE       0.3963213,0.2214044,0.7758861,0.7604822,0.1539518,0.3723510,...
#> 2500: Sub-district 10        50       30     10      FALSE       0.3252003,0.8661620,0.6096993,0.1530726,0.1046206,0.5931892,...
```

The final step is to sample the number of positive individuals surveyed at each site and then clean up the table.

```
dtSamples[
  ,`:=`(
    # simulate the number of positive people for each village
    n_pos = {
      n_pos <- rbinom(sum(n_village), rep(n_person, n_village), unlist(site.prev))
      p_hat <- n_pos/rep(n_person, n_village)
      relist(n_pos, site.prev)
    },
    p_hat = relist(p_hat, site.prev),
    site.prev = NULL,
    sample_all = NULL
  )
][]
#>           shapeName_3 n_village n_person sim_id                 n_pos                             p_hat
#>    1:  Sub-district 1         5       10      1             1,6,2,9,9               0.1,0.6,0.2,0.9,0.9
#>    2:  Sub-district 2         5       10      1         0, 1,10, 2, 0               0.0,0.1,1.0,0.2,0.0
#>    3:  Sub-district 3         5       10      1             5,5,9,4,4               0.5,0.5,0.9,0.4,0.4
#>    4:  Sub-district 4         5       10      1             2,8,1,2,2               0.2,0.8,0.1,0.2,0.2
#>    5:  Sub-district 5         5       10      1             0,7,6,1,2               0.0,0.7,0.6,0.1,0.2
#>   ---                                                                                                  
#> 2496:  Sub-district 6        50       30     10  4,25, 9, 0,14, 5,... 0.16,1.00,0.36,0.00,0.56,0.20,...
#> 2497:  Sub-district 7        50       30     10 23,19, 1,13,20, 0,... 0.92,0.76,0.04,0.52,0.80,0.00,...
#> 2498:  Sub-district 8        50       30     10 19,23,21,24, 3,12,... 0.76,0.92,0.84,0.96,0.12,0.48,...
#> 2499:  Sub-district 9        50       30     10  0,19, 6,16,19, 8,... 0.00,0.76,0.24,0.64,0.76,0.32,...
#> 2500: Sub-district 10        50       30     10 24, 8,22, 3, 9, 3,... 0.96,0.32,0.88,0.12,0.36,0.12,...
```

---

Putting it all together and timing the full 6,425,000-sample dataset:

```
n_subdist <- 257L
n_sites <- 3836L
n_sims <- 1e3L

admin_unit_df <- data.table(
  shapeName_0 = "Country 1", 
  shapeName_1 = "Region 1",
  shapeName_2 = "District 1",
  shapeName_3 = paste0("Sub-district ", 1:n_subdist)
)

dtSites <- setorder(
  data.table(
    site_id = sample(n_sites),
    shapeName_3 = sample(admin_unit_df$shapeName_3, n_sites, 1),
    site.prev = runif(n_sites)
  ), shapeName_3, site_id
)

admin_unit_df[dtSites[, .(n_sites = .N), shapeName_3], on = "shapeName_3", n_sites := n_sites]

system.time({
  dtSamples <- setDT(
    expand.grid(
      shapeName_3 = admin_unit_df$shapeName_3,
      n_village = c(5, 10, 20, 30, 50),
      n_person = seq(10, 30, 5),
      sim_id = 1:n_sims
    )
  )[
    # don't try to sample more than are available
    admin_unit_df, on = "shapeName_3", sample_all := n_village >= n_sites
  ][
    # collapse the site prevalences by sub-district, then join to dtSamples
    dtSites[,.(site.prev = .(site.prev)), shapeName_3],
    on = "shapeName_3",
    # for each sample, sample the required number of site prevalences (if
    # there aren't enough sites to sample, survey all of them)
    site.prev := lapply(
      1:.N,
      function(i) {
        if(sample_all[i]) {
          site.prev[[i]] 
        } else {
          sample(site.prev[[i]], n_village[i])
        }
      }
    )
  ][
    ,`:=`(
      # simulate the number of positive people for each village
      n_pos = {
        n_pos <- rbinom(sum(n_village), rep(n_person, n_village), unlist(site.prev))
        p_hat <- n_pos/rep(n_person, n_village)
        relist(n_pos, site.prev)
      },
      p_hat = relist(p_hat, site.prev),
      site.prev = NULL,
      sample_all = NULL
    )
  ]
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>  132.74    4.68  137.39

dtSamples[]
#>               shapeName_3 n_village n_person sim_id                 n_pos                       p_hat
#>       1:   Sub-district 1         5       10      1        10, 9, 7, 2, 6         1.0,0.9,0.7,0.2,0.6
#>       2:   Sub-district 2         5       10      1             2,0,4,7,6         0.2,0.0,0.4,0.7,0.6
#>       3:   Sub-district 3         5       10      1             0,3,4,1,8         0.0,0.3,0.4,0.1,0.8
#>       4:   Sub-district 4         5       10      1             0,4,8,0,2         0.0,0.4,0.8,0.0,0.2
#>       5:   Sub-district 5         5       10      1             8,2,7,4,0         0.8,0.2,0.7,0.4,0.0
#>      ---                                                                                             
#> 6424996: Sub-district 253        50       30   1000 10,10, 1, 5, 4, 9,... 1.0,1.0,0.1,0.5,0.4,0.9,...
#> 6424997: Sub-district 254        50       30   1000  9, 3,10, 8,10, 8,... 0.9,0.3,1.0,0.8,1.0,0.8,...
#> 6424998: Sub-district 255        50       30   1000       5,6,2,6,2,9,... 0.5,0.6,0.2,0.6,0.2,0.9,...
#> 6424999: Sub-district 256        50       30   1000       8,7,1,0,8,7,... 0.8,0.7,0.1,0.0,0.8,0.7,...
#> 6425000: Sub-district 257        50       30   1000       7,9,8,7,0,2,... 0.7,0.9,0.8,0.7,0.0,0.2,...
```